# Set of values of $\frac{x^3\sin\left(x^3\right)}{x^2+2x\cos x + 2}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

How to find the set of values of $$f(x)=\frac{x^3\sin(x^3)}{x^2+2x\cos x + 2}?$$

I tried using Taylor series, limiting, comparing and derivation but none of these worked for me. Have you got any tips on how to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We have
$$
f(x)
 = \frac{x\sin(x^3)}{1+2x^{-1}\cos x + 2x^{-2}}
$$
so as $x \to \infty$, the denominator approaches 1 and the denominator oscillates with linear amplitude, which suggests that the range $f(x)$ is the set of all real numbers.

The intuition is supported by the graph of $f(x)$ over $x \in [0,20]$ from [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5Bx%5E3+*+Sin%5Bx%5E3%5D%2F(x%5E2%2B2*x*Cos%5Bx%5D%2B2),%7Bx,0,20%7D%5D):

[image: plot of the function]

Can you formally prove it?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I can. But I wonder why my question was downvoted.

Comment: @FilipWichrowski I did not downvote, but there are many people here who are of the philosophy that you are suppose to exhibit some of your own work even when posting the question. That position is hard to argue with, since this is not supposed to be "we do your homework gor you" kind of site :-). There is a lot of grey area in the matter and some people use it differently than others...

Comment: Of course, I totally agree with this point of view. Nevertheless, I did post an information that I had tried a few methods that probably were not the best ones out there. By the way, it is not my homework. I'm just keen on figuring out math problems.

Comment: @FilipWichrowski You are preaching to the choice :) I prefer to hint instead of downvoting, except in really obnoxious cases. But I did upvote your question nevertheless. Next time, likely posting some details in the arguments that did not work would help.

Comment: Sure. Thanks again!